# Laravel 5 Queries Cache

Tags: laravel, caching, laravel-5

I have a website built in Laravel 5.2 that supports multiple languages. Most of the website contents are coming from MySQL database. I cache most of my queries. Example:

```
$categories = Cache::remember('Categories', 1440, function()
    {
        return $this->category->getAllOrderByRank();
    });
```

The problem is when I visit the English version of the website the query results get saved. Then when I change the language to Deutsch, The query is still cached and showing the English data from database. Do you guys have any suggestions of how I can handle this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd include the locale in the cache name:

```
$locale = App::getLocale();

$categories = Cache::remember('Categories.' . $locale, 1440, function()
{
    return $this->category->getAllOrderByRank();
});
```

That way if you're set to `en` you'll pull `Categories.en` query, if you're set to `de` you'll get `Categories.de`, etc.

I'm wondering, though, where are you doing the translations? This probably shouldn't be affected by a cached query.

Comment: Thank you Samsquanch. Most of the translation is stored in database.

Comment: @rafiaTech what cache driver are you using? sorry, I am not sure why you are reading the texts from a cache memory instead of reading it from the database... the cache is always faster? in that case, we should apply cache strategies for the most of our data?